# A word to describe the relationship between a child and its parent?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm keeping a list of relationships between children and their parents:

```
{
  child A -> parent A,
  child B -> parent B,
  ...,
}
```

I want to find a word that describes the relationship between a child and its parent. In plural, the word could be used to describe the list itself.

For context, the children and parents in question are not humans, or even living things. The relationships are figurative, but I think it is safe to ignore that distinction.

Here are some thoughts I've had so far:

- A fraternal relationship (i.e. a relationship between siblings) could be described as a "fraternity".
- The relationship between two married people is often described as a "marriage".
- If a person is a dependent on someone (say financially dependent on their parent) you might declare that relationship a "dependence".

The ideal word will allude to the fact that the children are on the left side of the list, and the parents are on the right side.

Comment: An example sentence would clarify (and is required by site rules). "Child" is the relationship of a child to the parents, so I'm a bit lost.

Comment: I recommend that you check the meaning of _filial_ in a dictionary and see if that's the word you're looking for.

Comment: Child .... Child's Relationship .... Parent

Comment: *The relationship between two married people is often described as a "marriage".* This is simply inaccurate and misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to this party, but I think **heritage** makes the most sense here, especially since the list is organized from the perspective of the 'children'.

Answer (score 1):

> [***parentage***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/parentage) - When you refer to people's parentage, you mean their parents and/or their parent's country and social class

It's traditionally a "where they come from" sort of thing.

*Parentage* is usually not a synonym for *parenthood*, the state of being a parent, though it can be used in that sense.

So "parentage list" might work.

Comment: "Parentage list" would be a list of the parents and have little to do with the relationship between the child and their parents.

Answer (score 1):

**Parent-child** relationship:

> An alternative solution is the expression of the hierarchy as a **parent-child** relation. Celko called this the adjacency list model.
> ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model))

Also see: [adjacency](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=adjacency) and [parenthood](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55875504/getting-parenthood-of-tree-structure) on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Filial, adjective: relating to, or befitting a son or daughter. filial obedience. : being or having the relation of a child or offspring

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Symbiotes / Symbionts - organisms living in symbiosis with another.

Since the child and parent relationship is figurative Symbiotes or Symbionts which is living in an interactive, long-term relationship.

Comment: While this might describe a young child and their parent, I'm not sure it still applies to adult children (who might be living very separate lives)